# Aligning text next to an image vertically

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a blog from scratch and I am having trouble aligning text next to the top of an image. Currently the the text is to right of the image however it is centered. How do I align the text to the top?

HTML

```
<img class="left" src="images/test.jpg" height="153" width="186" align="left">
<p class="right">bLAH BLAH BLAH</p>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

CSS

```
.left{
    display:inline-block;
    clear:left;
}

.right{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    clear:right;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this and let me know if it helps:

```
.left {display:block;float:left;}

.right {float:left;margin-left:20px;}
```

Comment: Its works kinda of. The first 2 lines of text are aligned properly howver te third lines acts as if there is no margin?

Answer (score 0):

Text is aligned to the *left* by default so, you wouldn't need `align:left`. Also, FYI it is `text-align:left;`
**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/r2SWx/

```
<p  class="left"><img src="images/test.jpg" height="153" width="186"></p><p class="right">bLAH BLAH BLAH</p>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```